# How to fix HTML1502: Unexpected DOCTYPE error message in IE 10?

Tags: html, doctype, internet-explorer-10

I have an application which works fine on IE8 and IE9. But the same application throws errors similar to the following on IE10. Any one knows what changed in IE10 that can trigger this issue?

```
HTML1502: Unexpected DOCTYPE. Only one DOCTYPE is allowed and it must occur 
before any elements.

HTML1513: Extra "<html>" tag found. Only one "<html>" tag should exist per 
document.
```

In my application I have a set of main jsp which included other jsps on a need basis. Each jsp has a  and  tag in it.

Comment: please show the rendered html. We can't help you from the error message alone. However, it seems like you render something twice, so two doctype and html tags are in the resulting markup.

Comment: As the error _clearly_ states, your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you posted, your document has more than one `html` element and more than one doctype. Only one of each are allowed to be a conforming html document. If you remove the extra ones, the error should go away.

If you want to include multiple pages in one, you should include the subpages in an `<iframe>`.

It is hard to know for absolute certain without seeing your source code however.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of using an older doc type. once I added the new HTML 5 doctype the issue is resolved.